Is there any way to group points with ellipses based on two variables?
I have a data frame with five variables and 108 observations.
pacman:: p_load (factoextra, FactoMineR, tidyverse)

> dput (head (bq))

structure(list(Treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Replicate = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3), ParticleSize = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
), Concentration = c(0, 0, 0, 25, 25, 25), Mass = c(0.238, 0.249, 
0.263, 0.239, 0.245, 0.246)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> head (bq)

  Treatment Replicate ParticleSize Concentration  Mass
1         1         1          100             0 0.238
2         1         2          100             0 0.249
3         1         3          100             0 0.263
4         1         1          100            25 0.239
5         1         2          100            25 0.245
6         1         3          100            25 0.246

pbq  <- PCA (X = bq, scale.unit = T, graph = F)
var1 <- pbq$eig [1, 2]
var2 <- pbq$eig [2, 2]

gpb <- pbq |>

fviz_pca_biplot (title         = NULL, 
                 arrowsize     = 1.25,
                 label         = "var",
                 repel         = T,
                 font.family   = "TNR",
                 labelsize     = 5,
                 col.var       = "black",
                 pointshape    = 16,
                 pointsize     = 4.5,
                 col.ind       = as.factor (bq$Treatment),
                 addEllipses   = T,
                 ellipse.type  = "t", 
                 ellipse.level = 0.95,
                 ellipse.alpha = 0.2) +

labs (x     = paste0 ("Dimension 1 (", round (var1, 2), "%)"), 
      y     = paste0 ("Dimension 2 (", round (var2, 2), "%)"),
      color = "Effect in") +

theme (axis.title       = element_text  (family = "OS", face = "bold", size = 18, color = "black"),
       axis.title.x     = element_text  (margin = margin (t = 20)),
       axis.title.y     = element_text  (margin = margin (r = 20)),
       axis.text        = element_text  (family = "TNR", face = "plain", size = 16, color = "black"),
       legend.position  = "top",
       legend.title     = element_text  (family = "TNR", face = "plain", size = 16, color = "black",
                                         margin = margin (r = 25)),
       legend.text      = element_text  (family = "TNR", face = "plain", size = 14, color = "black"),
       panel.background = element_blank (),
       panel.grid.major = element_line  (color = "gray90"),
       panel.grid.minor = element_line  (color = "gray90")) +

scale_color_manual (labels = c("Reducing carbohydrate", "Total protein", "Chlorophyll A autofluorescence"),
                    values = c("1" = "#85B3F7", "2" = "#91C740", "3" = "#FFBB3C")) +
  
windows (); gpb


This code doesn't have any problems that I need to solve. However, I wanted to add ellipses that circle points that share the same treatment AND particle size... Is that possible? Haven't found anything about it on the internet

https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_mark_ellipse.html?
